# Google Search Console shows two different "Last crawled" dates for the same URL. Which one is correct?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot

For the same URL (x):

*Coverage > Indexed, not submitted on sitemap > Examples > URL x > Last Crawled* shows "**Mar 29, 2020**".

*Inspect URL > URL x > Coverage > Last crawl* shows "**Apr 4, 2020, 2:47:23 AM**".

Which one is the right one? Meaning, when was the last time googlebot crawled through that URL?

Comment: I'd go with the value in the inspect tool. I've seen those summaries out of date before. You can also check the cache: for the page as that shows a date and timezone. I think the dates in the GSC are in your own timezone.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath good call. Cache matches URL inspection tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The cache date matches URL inspection tool "last crawl", so that's the right one.

(Thanks to Tony for pointing me in the right direction in the comments.)